# Issues with AjaxMin 5.14 and Report Viewer in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer, ajaxmin

I have the newest version of `AjaxMin` installed `AjaxMin 5.14.5506.26202` in my ASP.Net project. I have tried to use the Report Viewer designer, and I receive an that it can't find the older version of AjaxMin.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with the new version of the Report Viewer.

Can some please tell me how I can use the report view with the new version of AjaxMin?

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install the old version again using the neget console

```
Install-Package AjaxMin -Version 4.97.4951.28483
```